Restrict Traffic in Static Web App only for Azure Front Door
I set up a premium Front Door for my Static Webapp (& other App Services).
Everything works fine but now I would like to restrict traffic going directly to the static web app.
I followed this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/front-door-manual?tabs=azure-portal&pivots=swa-afd-manual-afd
And based on the guide i came up with the following code:
"networking": {
  "allowedIpRanges": ["AzureFrontDoor.Backend"]
}
"forwardingGateway": {
  "requiredHeaders": {
    "X-Azure-FDID" : "<my Front Door ID>"  },  "allowedForwardedHosts": [
    "<Front Door Endpoint>.z01.azurefd.net", "<my custom Domain>"
  ]
}

Unfortunately i always get 403 when i try to browse the Front Door URL. No Matter if i only try it with the netwroking section only, or forwarding Gateway. Does anyone know what i am doing wrong? And what tool is best to troubleshoot something like this?

I am able to access the App with my Front Door URL

The issue seems to be with your staticwebapp.config.json file.Once try it by removing your Custom domain.
